# kick a user out if cookie has expired when clicking a link

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies, hyperlink

I have some good code to check if cookie has expired and kicks the user out.  However, this is triggered on the Page_Load function of the master page so it ignores all the links to external sites (which are many on my site). A friend of mine suggested I parse the link through an aspx page to trigger the event but I tried and am having trouble as the link needs to open a new window also.  Does anyone know the best way to acheive my goal?  I am coding with vb.net.  Thank you.

I have:

     
     `Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        If Not Request.Cookies("userDetails") Is Nothing Then

            txtUserInfo.Text = (Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("userDetails")) 
     & " [ " & Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("userDetails")    ("userOrg")) & " ]")

        Else

            Response.Redirect("~/LogOut.aspx")

        End If

    End Sub`

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem better. You have a site with a bunch of links to an external site not controlled by you? And you want to intercept all users clicking the physical link on your site and perform processing prior to sending them to the other site?

Comment: Thanks David.  Yes that's correct I have a lot of links to other sites and when the user clicks the link (<asp:Hyperlink>) I would like to trigger a request to see if the cookie has expired or not.

Comment: I will suggest an answer below, this would require that you create a "handler" to intercept the requests and do server side processing. This will require that the URLs point to your own site, but also include some information as to where the user should go.

Comment: I added a secondary answer that shows how to do this using ASP.NET's LinkButton "command event" which gets raised when a user clicks the link.

Comment: I deleted the answers that were not used. I provided one more.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the links to normal [HtmlAnchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you really need LinkButton, you can redirect an expired cookie on the [PreRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the Load.

Answer (score 0):

Add some javascript to check if the cookie exists, if so, redirect the user, otherwise make them log in.

```
<script>
     function openTab(url) {
        // check does the cookie exist?
        // This is not security in any way, this just checks that a cookie exists, which easily can be forged or tampered or whatever
        // the only way to truly make this secure and/or validate the users identity is to communicate with the web server. I would recommend using AJAX.
        if (document.cookie.indexOf("userDetails") >= 0) {
            var newtab = window.open(url, '_blank');
            newtab.focus();
        } else {
            window.location.href = "/LogIn.aspx"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Next, add the event to your ASP:HYPERLINK's onclick:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Google.com" NavigateUrl="#" onclick="openTab('http://www.google.com');" />
```

Comment: Thanks very much David R, I appreciate all your help.  For security reasons I will look at using AJAX to get my desired result.